# Rules for a novice DBA to follow when designing tables

Tags: database-design, rdbms

I'm sure in SO there are thousands of DBA who have experience on designing optimized database.
I'll request them to share some of their experience on:

- How to design a table *[with more read, less write/ less read, more write scenario]*?
- What are the common errors beginners make when designing tables?
- And if possible some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very broad - and so is my answer (this is for a typical line-of-business app - not a datawarehouse or decision support system):

- Use the **appropriate** data types - don't store a date in a string field - don't store numeric values in a string field (I've seen it all done before!); if your strings are 60-100 characters - don't use `VARCHAR(MAX)` (2 GB) in SQL Server..... if you have fixed length strings (e.g. codes) of less than 5 characters - use `CHAR(x)` not `VARCHAR(x)` and so on....
- **Normalize** your data - try to achieve third normal form - and *then* denormalize, where needed and appropriate. But first design to 3NF normalization levels. This also means: **every** table has a well-defined primary key.
- Use **constraints** where appropriate - foreign key relations between child and parent tables, constraints on the values permitted in a single column and uniqueness constraints.
- Think very hard about your **query access** - what tables will be queried how? Think about possible indices - but don't overdo it! Too many indices can be worse than none at all. Find a balance.

Plus there are some vendor-specific optimizations / things-to-do.

I.e. in SQL Server, I would:

- always put an index on the foreign key fields - it helps with JOIN's and with speeding up the ensuring of referential integrity
- often move large blob fields (`VARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARBINARY(MAX)`) to separate tables and link them to the "base" tables. That way, if you're using e.g. an ORM, you won't be loading all those huge blob of bytes into memory all the time.

This article [Fundamentals of Relational Database Design](http://r937.com/relational.html) by Paul Litwin sums it up quite nicely.

Comment: +1 for a good answer but you did not said what to use for "strings of 60-100 characters "

Comment: @Sourav: any string of more than 10 chars should be `VARCHAR` - when you have 60-100 characters, the 2 byte overhead of the `VARCHAR` (vs. just `CHAR`) aren't a problem anymore and the fact it only stores as much data as present is beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first rule is that One Database cannot do everything. It cannot be optimised for both Read and Write intensive operations. So you can have multiple databases each with a specific purpose.

**An Operational Database**

For the actual day to day running updating, reading, writing or the application(s) the system that the end users access. This should be in the [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) however you can break the NF and [denormalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) some fields if needed to improve slow queries

**Reporting Database**

This database (data warehouse) is optimised for READ only operations. It will be [denomoralised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and often as a [star schema.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)

**Staging Database**

If you need multiple applications to access your data. You can make a staging database which has a copy of all the data in your operational DB the main difference is this DB should not have any INDEXES or many constraints, triggers etc, as they all slow down INSERTS (writes). This DB is just used as a temporary storage for QUICKLY extracting all production data, but no other application should work directly with this DB. Other applications should extract the data they need from it and put into their own format. For example Copy data from the Staging into the Reporting/data warehouse. Its main purpose is to reduce the load on the operational database.

So the main point is for your operational database you should learn about [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and if you want to do lots of inserts pay attention to what triggers and indexes you have on your fields as they slow down inserts.  Also take a look at the NOSQL databases for potentially even better performance.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a DBA, only a programmer so I may be completely wrong =) and I an open to suggestions.

Comment: +1 for straightforward answer :) But i hate the 'NoSQL' in this case cause i've tagged this question in RDBMS, and i dont think NoSQL is an RDBMS (i can be wrong too :( )